# Can I merge Web-Client Account with Service Account?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I have an app setup with the Web-Client structure, using it as a kind of server manager for many users. They can't access the account but only some folders, as I do all the authorization steps by code. I chose this kind of account in Drive API so I could upload big files, as service accounts were very limited. But now there are some files that can be uploaded through the Web drive.google.com domain, and I need to own this files that the e-mails from my same domain have uploaded. So I was thinking if it was possible to have a service account to change permissions only, and do all the file uploads though the Web-Client Account within the same project and email? Thanks.

Comment: if the service account has access to the folder it can update the permissions on the files within.    What exactly are the limits to service accounts you speak of?

Comment: The limits were the quota and petitions, as well as max file upload size. That's why I had to use the other type of account. Now i want to change permissions for any user within my domain of the files they uploaded so the drive account has the ownership of all files. Most documents are uploaded within my code but there are some others that aren't, so that's why I want to impersonate users with a service account, but within the same project.